# improve application performance and intelligence

Tags: .net, performance, memory-management, windows-services, cpu-usage

I have a question which is related to application performance and intelligence.

I have created a window service, if I run it on a 3 different configuration machines. I want it to utilize appropriate resources of machine (CPU and memory).

Say Machine 1(M1) have single core with 1 GB ram.

Machine2 (M2) has two cores with 2 GB ram.

Machine3 (M3) has 4 cores with 4 GB ram.

Now when my service runs on it, it should utilize proper resource. Like if cpu use of machine is 1% it should go on user upto 50% or more. If it’s already 50% use only 30%. So do ram. But never cross a limit like 90% or something.

Basically I wrote a multithreaded service which right now don’t care about machine resources and keep on utilizing it. I want to include this intelligence in it.

Please help me out with your ideas.

Thanks

Comment: I am asking this question because my application can run on any configuration machine. In case if its running on a single threaded machine its going to alomst access all resources like 100% and almost 70 to 80% memory.

I dont want it that way. I want to create a perfect resource governer which can run on any kind of configuration machine and still works perfectly

Comment: Can you just set your thread to the low priority, so it will utilize the system resources only if nobody wants to use them?

Comment: I am not at all playing with thread preorites, just plan threads. As it can cause resource starvation. I want to prevent it and manually handle that so the my service runs elegantly on any kind of system configuration.

Comment: As far as I know Windows gives only one puller to control thread activeness - the priority. You can tweak CPU usage only by this parameter. But I don't think you expect this to be the answer, so I'll wait here with you for somebody to prove me wrong :)

Comment: I am not denying what you are trying to convey me Archeg. But i would say increasing thread priority is not good thread design.
What i am trying to achieve is increase threads based on cpu uses by using a thread monitor and with help of a resource governor.
Thread monitor i already have i need to create a resource governor which will guide me whether or increase or decrease threads under execution.
Something like this is going on in my mind right now. I am waiting for better feed back who had done such kind of stuff before.

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. A thread count shouldn't be decreased/increased because of the system load. That way you are trying to lie to the windows scheduler, but windows scheduler is pretty clever to find out what process is good to be increased or decreased. What is reasonable is to increase the thread count if you have more than one precessor. You can read more in the book "Patterns of Parallel Programming" (Stephen Toub). TPL have constructions that should resolve this problem automatically, so you don't need to think about this.

Answer (score 4):

As Archeg said, based on the number of processors, you can increase the thread count. But increasing the number of threads based on CPU activity is the wrong way to go about it.

Look at it this way - the CPU scheduler allocates time-slots at a millisecond granularity. If the load on the system from other processes is low, it *will give your process more time. Period.* If there are lots of processes, *you will get time-slots less often*. You shouldn't thrash it with more threads than necessary.

What you need to do is decide *what* you want to do. Is the service time-sensitive? If so, then in a heavily-loaded system, you have less CPU time to operate with, and in an idle system, you can use more CPU time within the same, say, second. *Beware: If your service does I/O, maybe your service itself throttles how much CPU it can use.*

With RAM, you could do something like, given how much free RAM the system has, switch algorithms to one that uses less processing or processes faster, but needs more memory (and vice-versa).

The point is that there's no 'service-independent' way to do this kind of intelligent scaling, besides better schedulers (which is something a lot of smart people have been looking at for many many years). You can however write services that are aware of current system constraints and change behavior accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Building high-performance .NET applications is significantly easier if you design with performance in mind. Make sure you develop a performance plan from the outset of your project. Never try to add performance as a post-build step. Also, use an iterative development process that incorporates constant measuring between iterations.

By following best practice design guidelines, you significantly increase your chances of creating a high-performance application.
 **Consider the following design guidelines:**

- **Consider security and performance.**
- **Partition your application logically.**
- **Evaluate affinity.**
- **Reduce round trips.**
- **Avoid blocking on long-running tasks.**
- **Use caching.**
- **Avoid unnecessary exceptions.**